# how to set the value of textarea with toolbar using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying (from my firefox extension) to set the value of a textarea with toolbar which placed when creating a blog before posting it like in blogger or live-journal.

In simple textarea I can get or set the textarea value by:

```
var myTextArea = gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
alert(myTextArea.value); // alerts the old value
myTextArea.value = "this is the new value of the textarea";
```

where there of course was only one textarea.

The problem is in textarea with toolbar. 
I succeeded changing the value of the textarea i'm writing in right now even though it has toolbar, but in all other sites especially blog sites the element value is changed but the text in the page stays the same.

I thought maybe the textarea is CKEditor but I don't know it's name so I can't use:

```
FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('InstanceName').insertText("new value in textarea");
```

is the textarea in sites such as mentioned above is CKEditor? and more important - how do i set the it's value?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do:

```
for(x in CKEDITOR.instances) {
  CKEDITOR.instances[x].insertText("new value in textarea");
}
```

Comment: it's not working. what is "CKEDITOR"? is it a global instance I can access from anyplace or is it part of the document? I also tried "gBrowser.contentDocument.CKEDITOR.instances" also but it does not work either.

Comment: In your case, you might need to replace that with FCKeditorAPI. CKEDITOR is name of the global object in newer versions of CKEditor. Also can you provide the link you tested this with?

Comment: but FCKeditorAPI has no "instances" property. so how to get the instances? I tried in [here](http://www.livejournal.com/update.bml) and in [here](http://www.blogger.com/post-create.g?blogID=6715480188653567897). I don't know if you will have access because it is from my account. thank you.

Comment: I just checked the blogger edit post page. They are not using CKEditor! The answer i gave works only for pages that use CKEditor. Google seems to be using some custom 'richedit' component. Let me check the other page.

Comment: The livejournal post page does use CkEditor and the answer i gave works perfectly on it i.e. `for(x in CKEDITOR.instances) {
  CKEDITOR.instances[x].insertText('Hello');
})`. You can try running it using Firebug console.

Comment: actually i checked and there is "Instances" property to FCKeditorAPI as you can see [here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10902). so it didn't work for me because blogger is not using CKEditor. so how can I set the value of this custom 'richedit'? thanks again.

Comment: For blogger's edit post page, you can do this: `document.getElementById('richeditorframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = 'Hi There';` - But this is not a generic solution. As you probably understood by now, the way you set it will be different for different sites.